Slow `outer` in `Rmpfr`
I've found outer in Rmpfr to be very slow compared to vector multiplication after rep. I've tried outer, %*%, and tcrossprod.
library(Rmpfr)

m <- 100
n <- 50
x <- mpfr(runif(m), 128)
y <- mpfr(runif(n), 128)

bench::mark(
  outer = outer(x, y),
  tcrossprod = tcrossprod(x, y),
  "%*%" = x%*%t(y),
  repmult = matrix(rep(x, n)*rep(y, each = m), m, n),
  relative = TRUE
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 outer       89.5   67.7      1.51      525.     1   
#> 2 tcrossprod  83.7   63.3      1.61      513.     1.18
#> 3 %*%        135.   102.       1         517.     1.36
#> 4 repmult      1      1      101.          1      2.00

That's a 60x speed difference for a moderately sized matrix. The difference grows roughly linearly with the size of the final matrix. This is using the default R BLAS.
Why is it so slow? Is matrix(rep( the best way to go here?

Update - as pointed out by @GKi, outer here is calling tcrossprod. I suspect the same sort of behavior may carry over to Rmpfr matrix multiplication in general so the real question is what makes tcrossprod so slow.

You could look through/profile Rmpfr:::.matmult.R (selectMethod("tcrossprod", c("mpfr", "mpfr")))

Thanks for the tip, Ben. It's just a double-loop calling R_mpfr_sumprod for each element of the return matrix. Not at all optimized.

FWIW, there are a lot of things in both Rmpfr and gmp that could be cleaned up, optimized, made more  DWIM-ish, etc.  It's a big job and I bet the package maintainers & authors would welcome help.

@CarlWitthoft, for sure. This wasn't meant to be a complaint or criticism. I still think it's a fabulous package. Just trying to get my expectations set correctly. And looking a little into how to optimize matrix multiplication here, it's definitely not trivial.

In outer you can find if (is.character(FUN) && FUN == "*") { which is calling tcrossprod(as.vector(X), as.vector(Y)).
But if you use:
outer(x, y, `*`)

it calls:
FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
Y <- rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y)))
if (length(X)) 
  X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
FUN(X, Y, ...)

What will be faster for class mpfr.
library(Rmpfr)

m <- 100
n <- 50
x <- mpfr(runif(m), 128)
y <- mpfr(runif(n), 128)

bench::mark(
  outer = outer(x, y),
  outer2 = outer(x, y, `*`),
  tcrossprod = tcrossprod(x, y),
  "%*%" = x%*%t(y),
  repmult = matrix(rep(x, n)*rep(y, each = m), m, n)
)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 outer        1.33s   1.33s     0.753     195MB     18.8     1    25      1.33s
#2 outer2     13.62ms 21.04ms    40.9       375KB     25.3    21    13    513.5ms
#3 tcrossprod   1.66s   1.66s     0.601     195MB     16.2     1    27      1.66s
#4 %*%          2.13s   2.13s     0.469     196MB     22.5     1    48      2.13s
#5 repmult    13.93ms 23.19ms    41.7       349KB     28.5    22    15   527.17ms

For the class mpfr tcrossprod is currently much slower than the alternatives. For numeric it is fast.
m <- 1000
n <- 500
x <- runif(m)
y <- runif(n)

bench::mark(
  outer = outer(x, y),
  outer2 = outer(x, y, `*`),
  tcrossprod = tcrossprod(x, y),
  "%*%" = x%*%t(y),
  repmult = matrix(rep(x, n)*rep(y, each = m), m, n)
)
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 outer      530.21µs  585.7µs     1511.    3.81MB    151.    571    57
#2 outer2       1.46ms   2.15ms      476.   11.45MB    197.    116    48
#3 tcrossprod 499.78µs 626.61µs     1530.    3.81MB    114.    552    41
#4 %*%        543.13µs 643.67µs     1479.    3.82MB     98.1   603    40
#5 repmult      2.67ms   3.07ms      326.   11.44MB    127.     87    34


This makes the code more compact. Walking through outer, I see that outer(x, y, *) skips tcrossprod and proceeds to do essentially matrix(rep(x, n)*rep(y, each = m), m, n) (with a little overhead). Why tcrossprod is so slow is still a mystery to me, and it makes me wonder what any other hidden inefficiencies are in Rmpfr.

Just to be OCD-ish -- did you verify all.equal on the 3 versions you time-tested?

I think bench::mark checks all.equality (check=TRUE) by default:

@CarlWitthoft bench::mark checks per default for all.equal.

@GKi   good to know that!   Maybe I should stop using microbenchmark  :-)
